# Secure way to manage session with firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm building a simple front end webpage, which will use firebase to manage user login. As far as I have seen, when someone logs in to firebase, they will remain logged for 1 hour, and, I'll have to renew the token after that.

I'm using flutter, and I plan to store this "renew token" on the client side, so that, I can ask firebase to renew the user session without asking user to log in every hour.

My questions are the following:

- Is that a good/secure approach?
- How should I manage user session with firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase SDKs automatically handle the renewal of the ID token behind the scenes. You should not have to write any code for this to happen.

You also shouldn't have to persist any of the tokens yourself, as the Firebase SDKs also do this automatically, and restore the user authentication state when the app restarts.

All you should have to do is to [listen to the authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state). This listener is typically preferred over (solely) relying on `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` as the authentication state may change and the listener ensure your code automatically runs when this happens.